# The Area Of The Circle

Tags: geometry

If we consider a circle with center O, and a point on the circle say P.The radius will be the vector OP.Now, if we are to consider its area why don`t we multiply the radius OP by the perimeter of the circle, as in that of the rectangle,where one side of the figure the'other side' times gives the area of the figure.

Comment: Why would we do that? There's no clear reason why we would expect that to work, and in fact it gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Because it's not a rectangle? And the radius is not a side of the circle?

Comment: If the radius is $r$, then the perimeter is $2\pi r$, multiplying then will give you $2\pi r^2$, but the area is $\pi r^2$.

Comment: Multiplying by the perimeter gives you a $r\times 2\pi r$ rectangle, and when you twist and squeeze that to make it into a circle, you lose area.

Comment: [Hey, you're only off by a factor of two.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_disk#Rearrangement_proof)

Answer (score 1):

Draw a small circle with a radius of about 4cm on the left side of a piece of paper. Mark the radius vertically. Then roughly measure the perimeter. Now multiply the two, and draw the result as the second side of a rectangle, where the first side is the radius you already marked.

You will see that the (area of the) ractangle is *much* bigger than the circle.

($2$ times bigger to be precise, as $r\cdot2r\pi=2\cdot r^2\pi$, with $r^2\pi$ being the actual area of the circle.)